# Docker npm install with volumes mapping

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm following a tutorial for docker and docker compose. Although there is a `npm install` command in Dockerfile (as following), there is a situation that tutor have to run that command manually.

```
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
```

Because he is mapping the project current directory to the container by volumes as following:(which is like project runs in the container by mapped source code to the host directory)

```yaml
api:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
    environment:
      DB_URL: mongodb://db/vidly
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
```

So `npm install` command in docker file doesn't make any sense. So he runs this command directly in the root of project.

So, another developer has to run `npm install` as well, (or if I add a new package, I should do it too) which seems not very developer friendly. Because the purpose of docker is not to do the instructions by yourself. So `docker-compose up` should do everything. Any idea about this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: "*... there is a situation that tutor have to run that command manually.*" - In what situation exactly? I imagine the container to be a development container, otherwise we would not mount, but copy the code to the container.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I'm talking about development time. About the situation, I described later: *Because he is mapping the project*...

Comment: That is... vague. I would expect that the code is started with `npm start` or similar and is automatically reloaded when changes are detected (through `npm`, that's why we want the volume mount in the first place). I see no reason why we sould have to rebuild. But then again, I am not an expert in the javascript ecosystem and my knowledge in that regard is very limited.

Comment: How would you handle this for development without docker? This is a development vs building for tests/production issue. If you mount a local folder inside a docker container for your dev and you add/change dependencies while developing, you have to launch some commands to refresh your dev tree. Without docker you do it in your own local environment or a local/remote (virtual)machine. With docker and a bind mount, you do it inside the running container (and most IDE are docker aware and able to do this from their GUI today if you have people not comfortable with the command line).

Comment: @Zeitounator that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @zeitounator, who adds very sensible commentary to your situation and use.

However, if you did want to solve the original problem of running a container that volume mounts in code, and have it run a development server, then you could move the `npm` command from the `COPY` directive to the `CMD`, or even add an entry script to the container that includes the npm call.

That way you could run the container with the volume mount, and the starting process (`npm install`, `npm serve dev`, etc) would occur at ***runtime*** as opposed to ***buildtime***.

The best solution is as you mention yourself, Vahid, to use a smart Dockerfile that leverages sensible build caching, that allows the application to be built and ran with one command (and no external input). Perhaps you and your tutor can talk about these differences and come to an agreement